# What gold items should I sell to people as unidentified, which ones to identify and later on sell individually?

Tags: guild-wars

I am having quite a hard time guessing which skins for weapons and off-hands are considered favored thus getting high prices, and which count as plain skins and therefore to be sold bunched together for people going for the identification title.

I am using [GwEstimator](http://argos-soft.net/GwEstimator/) and often do price-checks in my alliance chat and of course google, but I have been playing for more then a year now and I feel like I am missing on some secret of what makes item really unique, and what makes them just merchant food/packages for identifiers.

I appreciate any thoughts and considerations you have while figuring out whether you are going to sell separately or wholesale.

Comment: FWIW, don't feel bad, I've been playing on and off for 6 years and I *still* don't feel like I have a handle on the market. GWEstimator makes my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime a gold weapon isn't max damage for its class, you should sell it as unIDed (such as a 8-16 damage sword, for instance).  Also, gold armor (depending on how lucky or not lucky you feel about getting a good rune).

For skins, it is a good idea to check [this thread](http://www.guildwarsguru.com/forum/rare-inscription-skins-price-guide-t10482377.html) to see what skins are rare and you should keep those.  Usually you want rare skins with low reqs (9 preferably).

Updating answer to address "do the requirement skill for holding the weapon matters as well?"

Yes, but only for extremely rare skins like the Bone Dragon Staff.  In those cases, even ones with useless skill reqs such as Smiting are worth less, than the more useful skills such as 9 Prot or 9 Heal.  Even still, because the skin is really rare, it's still worth a bunch of ectos.  General rule of thumb, if it's on that list in the link I provided above, it's worth something.  If not, then if it's something rare like Req 8 then it's probably worth a decent amount as well.  Other than that, you can choose to either ID for the title or hope for a good mod to sell (like +30 hp), or just sell as a junk id.

Oh, and one last thing, Canthan-only weapon skins tend to be worth more since they can't be modded with inscriptions.  So if you find a 15^50 weapon with reasonable req (like 9 or 10), it's worth getting some opinions on whether or not the skin is desirable.  The value has since dropped a bit due to the fact that the HoH chest can drop them in the inscribed form but they are still in good demand imo.

Comment: do the requirement skill for holding the weapon matters as well?

Comment: Yes, requirement usually matters a lot. Though, for ultra-rare skins, even an r13 will fetch a good fraction of the r9 price.

Answer (score 2):

I always identify every gold, because I want to get the identify title, and because in addition to the merch value, I also get the runes and mods of that item to sell them separately. On average, I gain more than selling the unidentified item. If the skin is rare and sought after, you can still sell it.

That is possibly a bit lazy though. If it still works that way, you can find out which mods an item has by equipping that item, for weapons and shields. The mods will still have effect even when unidentified. That way, you can judge whether or not the mods are worth selling separately.